# Is there an easier way to split strings than by using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have been using arrays to split my Strings. This is starting to become very tedious as my program continues to expand. Is there an easier way to do this without using arrays? I have been using arrays to individually store each char. can I store multiple chars, maybe a String, in an array?

Comment: Please add some context. What are you using the arrays for? To store the result? Why is that tedious?

Comment: Not sure what is difficult about arrays.... or string splitting... need more information

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html

Comment: `String[] stringArray = new String[2];` is an example of a string array, so the answer is yes you can use string arrays. Take a look at the Apache Commons StringUtils. You will likely find some good use out of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the class [**`com.google.common.base.Splitter`**](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) of [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) :

```
List<String> list = Splitter.on(',').splitToList("foo,bar,qux");
```

Or:

```
Iterable<String> iterator = Splitter.on(',').split("foo,bar,qux");
```

Comment: Very elegant. Would be nice if everyone used commons' libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of an easier way to split a `String` than `String#split(",")`.

If arrays annoy you, you can simply do the following

```
List<String> splitList = Arrays.asList(theString.split(","));
```

because the list is more flexible.

If this doesn't satisfy your question, you should be more specific.

*(I've given the comma regex as example)*

Comment: Pretty sure ^this^. I do not know that you would want to do splits without some sort of array/list behind it. If you want to hide the complexity, i.e. if you have a string with 3 pieces split by two commas, and you want the middle piece every time, then make a function and call it so you can hide the arrays from your sight from then on. Truth is, arrays are a basic part of programming, you are going to have to learn how to love them.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been using arrays to individually store each char. can I store
>   multiple chars, maybe a String, in an array?

Yes you can.

If you are looking for more helper methods, and easy functions that will help return string arrays and not just char arrays. Check out the Apache StringUtils

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Also you can use a 2d char array

```
char[][]
```

Or you can just use your String arrays

```
String[]
```

Regardless the StringUtils will have most everything you could need. If you find yourself copy pasting logic a lot, or writing the same kind of splitting logic again and again, wrap it in a function and just call that.